# Does Noether's theorem apply to bouncing black holes?

Tags: black-holes, energy-conservation, quantum-gravity, noethers-theorem, white-holes

[Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) states that every differentiable symmetry of the action of a physical system with conservative forces has a corresponding conservation law. Energy, however, is not conserved in an expanding spacetime because there is no symmetry on the time axis. This enables dark energy to exist and is the reason that general relativity does not conserve energy (except in symmetric situations).

My question is about how this translates to theories of [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) that predict the existence of spacetime that becomes spatiotemporally isolated near the center of a black hole. Examples are white holes, fecund universes, and collapsing wormholes. I know that black holes conserve energy, at least for an outside observer. So can energy be created in a disconnected region of spacetime at the other side of a black hole center for certain theories of quantum gravity? Or does Noether's theorem prevent this? (Bing insists that the theorem applies here, but I don't trust the answer.)

Comment: You are correct in not trusting Bing. Noether's theorem is just not available in GR. But I do not remember if there is something for QG.

Comment: Briefly speaking, Noether's theorem applies to classical (=non-quantum) theories with an action principle.

Comment: Nobody knows whether black holes actually conserve energy (or mass, electric charge, lepton number etc.). That is an assumption for which, to my knowledge, no precise experimental tests have been carried out, so far. Personally I wouldn't bet against it, but there is a difference between assuming something likely and actually testing it with experiments and observations.

Comment: As pointed out before Noether just is not valid in GR however you can still drow on the fact that Killing fields introduce conserves current though I have no clue if this translates to Quantum Gravity.

Comment: There are two sides to the Noether theorem. On one hand, it states that energy is conserved in time symmetry. On the other hand it states that energy is not conserved if there is no time symmetry. Both sides simply reflect the fact that time and energy are Fourier conjugates and therefore are in this relation. This fact holds in any branch of physics, SR, GR, classical, quantum, etc., so the comments above that this theorem is only classical are misleading. Perhaps the specific formulation is classical, but the relation between time and energy is exactly the same in quantum physics as well.